# Vodafone E3730 unable to usb_modeswitch

Tags: linux, drivers, modem, usb-modeswitch

#### tl;dr

Vodafone E3730 HSPA Express Data Card seems not to work at all in Kubuntu 18.04 LTS. How can I fix this?

---

#### Description

The card used to work. Frankly I don't remember if it worked in 18.04 LTS or in some earlier LTS version, but it did. In my current KDE Plasma in 18.04 LTS there are saved network settings that used to work. I expected them to kick in as soon as I insert the card but no; it's as if the card isn't there.

The SIM card was never removed and it should still work.

From the time it worked I remember no problems whatsoever. It probably worked almost out of the box. The hardware was recognized and I only had to set details like APN.

---

#### Technical details

This information is printed on a sticker:

> Vodafone Mobile Connect
> Model: E3730
> HSPA Express Data Card
>
> Designed in E.U. by Option
> Made in Ireland by Option
> QUALCOMM 3G CDMA

This is from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0af0:7301 Option
```

And this is from `usb-devices`:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0af0 ProdID=7301 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Option N.V.
S:  Product=Globetrotter HSUPA Modem
S:  SerialNumber=Serial Number
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
```

`cat /etc/issue`:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS \n \l
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux whatever 4.15.0-121-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 16:16:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

#### Research

It seems the right driver for the device is [`option`](https://superuser.com/a/691380/432690).

I learnt what [`usb_modeswitch`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/usb_modeswitch.1.html) is:

> Several new USB devices have their proprietary Windows drivers onboard, most of them WWAN and WLAN  dongles. When plugged in for the first time, they act like a flash storage and start installing the Windows driver from there. If the driver is installed, it makes the storage device disappear and a new device, mainly composite (e.g. with modem ports), shows up.
>
> On  Linux, in most cases the drivers are available as kernel modules, such as `usbserial` or  `option`. However, the device initially binds to `usb-storage` by default. `usb_modeswitch`  can then send a provided bulk message (most likely a mass storage command) to the device; this message has to be determined by analyzing the actions of the Windows driver.

I confirmed the packages `usb-modeswitch` and `usb-modeswitch-data` are installed. I believe they should work automatically. At least they seemingly used to work when my card used to work, without me knowing anything about `usb_modeswitch`.

I noticed the device does not even act like a flash storage. In the output of `usb-devices` (above) it states `Cls=08(stor.)`, which I believe indicates [Base Class 08h (Mass Storage)](https://www.usb.org/defined-class-codes#anchor_BaseClass08h); but the driver is `none`. No block device appears.

Then I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/818374/693277) and tried to adjust it to my hardware.

At first I created an empty file named `0af0:7301` in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/`. I removed and re-inserted the device. Then `usb-device` gave me this:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  7 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0af0 ProdID=7301 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Option N.V.
S:  Product=Globetrotter HSUPA Modem
S:  SerialNumber=Serial Number
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

The driver was `usb-storage` and I could actually mount a newly created block device (`/dev/sr0` in my case) and see it contains a Windows driver. I think the empty file had prevented `usb_modeswitch` from doing anything to the device.

Next I tried to run `usb_modeswitch` manually:

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x0af0 -p 0x7301 --option-mode
# or
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 0x0af0 -p 0x7301 --option-mode -C 0xff
```

Any of the above commands printed output suggesting it worked, but the only change in the output of `usb-device` was in this line:

```
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
```

This is what I had seen before I started to mess with `usb_modeswitch`. It seems I managed to manually recreate what `usb_modeswitch` had been doing automatically. My interpretation is the tool works only partially: it is able to remove the driver (`usb-storage` changes to `none`) but it doesn't switch the mode (`08(stor.)` remains).

---

#### Question

How to proceed from here? How can I make the modem work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### tl;dr

The device identifies with `Vendor=0af0`, `ProdID=7301`. Create a file named `0af0:7301` in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/` (or edit the file if it exists). Its content should be:

```
# Option HSO device
TargetClass=0xff
MessageContent="55534243785634120100000080000601000000000000000000000000000000"
NoDriverLoading=1
```

---

#### Investigation

<sub>(Note I am the asker and I'm answering my own question. Aside from tl;dr the answer is really a continuation of the story.)</sub>

The interpretation seems correct: `usb_modeswitch` does less than it should.

To learn what the tool tries to do to my device (when there is no `0af0:7301` file in `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/`), I consulted `apt-file show usb-modeswitch-data`. One of the lines looked promising:

```
/usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
```

And yes, this file contains many files named like `vendorID:productID`, including `0af0:7301` which reads:

```
# Option HSO device
TargetClass=0xff
OptionMode=1
```

I *guess* it specifies options I have already tried manually (in the question):

> ```
> usb_modeswitch -v 0x0af0 -p 0x7301 --option-mode -C 0xff
> ```

Because the hardware had worked in the past, I suspected the file had been different back then. I decided to find the (or an) old file.

The main entry in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
deb http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
```

(`pl` because I'm Polish). My intention was to find some older `usb-modeswitch-data` somewhere in `pl.archive.ubuntu.com`. After some digging I found this address:

```
ftp://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/
```

and downloaded this file:

```
ftp://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/usb-modeswitch-data/usb-modeswitch-data_20151101.orig.tar.bz2
```

After unpacking I found a file `0af0:7301` substantially different than `0af0:7301` from `/usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz`.

---

#### Solution

The content of the found file is:

```
# Option HSO device
TargetClass=0xff
MessageContent="55534243785634120100000080000601000000000000000000000000000000"
NoDriverLoading=1
```

I copied the file to `/etc/usb_modeswitch.d/`, removed and re-inserted the device. Then `usb-devices` gave me this output:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#= 10 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0af0 ProdID=7301 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Option N.V.
S:  Product=Globetrotter HSUPA Modem
C:  #Ifs=11 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 6 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
I:  If#= 7 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=option
I:  If#= 9 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
```

The device got recognized as a modem and my old network settings tried to kick in. The modem failed to connect though. After I restarted the OS the situation changed to:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0af0 ProdID=7301 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Option N.V.
S:  Product=Globetrotter HSUPA Modem
C:  #Ifs=11 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
I:  If#= 4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 6 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
I:  If#= 7 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
I:  If#= 8 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 9 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=hso
```

and *then* it started to work. Was the `option` driver the problem just before the restart? I don't know. Anyway, the device now works with `hso` and it seems this is the right driver nowadays.

---

#### Final notes

- It seems `--option-mode` that allegedly works with all Option devices doesn't really switch modes of my device. Explicitly specifying the right message seems crucial.
- This very answer was published using the device in question.